# Android Segmented Radio Button

Tags: android, radio-button, uisegmentedcontrol, radio-group

[image]

I have imported this method from https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton.
how to display a Views(may be Listview,Imageview or whatever) when each button is clicked.

here is the code..

```
    @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (group == segmentText) {
        if (checkedId == R.id.button_one) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Featured",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.button_two) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NearBy",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.button_three) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsup",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to set the visibility of each layouts gone/visible

Answer (score -1):

There are some ways you can implement as you have mentioned above:

**Solution 1:** Set visibility of particular Layout as and when related button is clicked.

**Solution 2:** You can take `ViewFlipper` with 3 different layouts, you just need to set the no. of child to be displayed inside ViewFlipper at a time.